# include a module into another nodeJS file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am just getting started with Node and wrote a little S3 reader that looks like the following. It sits in the *projectRoot/routes/S3Store.js* directory.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk'),
uploader = require('s3-upload-stream')(new AWS.S3()),
Q = require('q');

module.exports = S3Store;

function S3Store(config) {
    this.config = config;
    this.s3 = new AWS.S3({
    region: config.aws.region
    });
}

S3Store.prototype.readStream = function (filePath, metadata) {
var readConfig = {
    'Bucket': this.config.s3.bucketName,
    'Key': filePath
    };
return this.s3.getObject(readConfig).createReadStream();
}
```

Now, I created a new file *S3StoreMain.js* in *projectRoot/routes/S3StoreMain.js* and am trying to *import* the *S3Store.js* module like this:

```
var s3 = require('S3Store');
```

On running:

```
node S3StoreMain.js
```

It cannot find the module `S3Store`. Here is the stacktrace:

```
shubham@turing:~/Downloads/node-v0.12.4/exp2014$ node routes/S3StoreMain.js 

module.js:340
    throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'S3Store'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/shubham/Downloads/node-v0.12.4/exp2014/routes/S3StoreMain.js:1:72)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
shubham@turing:~/Downloads/node-v0.12.4/exp2014$
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Try doing `var s3 = require('./S3Store');`

Comment: just tried... doesn't help.

Comment: Try putting `module.exports = S3Store;` at the end of your file.

Comment: you need to write var s3 = require('./S3Store.js');

Comment: make sure you leave the require statement as per Bidhan A's first comment. It must be like this, so dont change it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Read this NodeJS API Reference](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules)

In order to require modules files relatively you need to use relative paths...  This is how the require module is designed with-in NodeJS (read the API docs linked for more information)

Try requiring the S3Store file from the S3StoreMain file like so:

```
var s3 = require("./S3Store");
```

You can omit the `".js"`, it's optional.

---

Note that everyone is saying you need to put your `modules.exports` at the end of the file... this is **false**!!  Due to how you defined your function, the referencing shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

You have to give the relative path of the module inside the `require` parameters if its not a npm module, because, if you will just give the name of the module in `require`, it will search for it in the `node_modules` folder.

So, use the following relative path and I hope it solves your problem.
`var s3 = require('./S3Store.js');`

Also, try to put the `module.exports` statement at the end of the file.

Comment: It doesn't matter where he puts the `module.exports` because of how he defined the function.  [See this JSFiddle for reference](http://jsfiddle.net/9wswbxue/1/)

Answer (score 0):

As many people suggested, one needs to use relative path while calling a module. So, something like this works for me:

```
var s3 = require('./S3Store');
```

Since I can only accept one answer, I will choose the one that has the best explanation.